# Custom file uploader with Selenium, Ajax

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a way to upload a file in Python with Selenium or another library. The problem is, this is a custom uploading system using Ajax, I cannot paste the path directly in the input file like this :

`s = driver.find_element_by_xpath("...") s.send_keys("...")`

One of my tough was to use POST request to directly upload the file but it's a bit complex, with encrypted data, token, multiple parts requests etc..

Another way would be to use the Robot framework but this way is a bit "hacky" and doesn't work on macos as I cannot paste directly the URL.

None of these solutions are suitable for me at the moment so I'm looking for another one.
Do you have any other idea of how to perform this ?

Thank you.